# Add images directory to makefile

Tags: ide, makefile, anjuta

I have a local folder which includes the icons I want to use at my program.The directory is /images/icons in the src directory.

When I make the tarball the directory with the images does not appear so i guess I have to include it in the makefile.If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Are you running a custom-built Makefile or a generator like `automake` ol `cmake`?

Comment: what's the line in your makefile that creates the tarball? because that sounds like a *really likely* place where you could, say, add directories to the tarball

Comment: @both I am using the anjuta IDE which makes the makefiles itself.It works and installs fine but i really need those images so any directions on how to edit the makefile?

Comment: this is not a C or GTK question, so it got retagged

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to edit generated makefiles-- they aren't designed to be edited. You should either write the makefiles by hand, or redirect the IDE as intended.

Comment: Good to know that, Beta. On the other hand is there any way i can include the directory? I am in a real hurry because I have to submit it somewhere in 2 days

Answer (score 0):

The `Makefile.am` in Anjuta has code in it to install images automatically:

```
@$(NORMAL_INSTALL)
if test -d $(srcdir)/pixmaps; then \
  $(mkinstalldirs) $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/pixmaps/$(PACKAGE); \
  for pixmap in $(srcdir)/pixmaps/*; do \
    if test -f $$pixmap; then \
      $(INSTALL_DATA) $$pixmap $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/pixmaps/$(PACKAGE); \
    fi \
  done \
fi
```

but it expects your images to be in `project_root/pixmaps`. If the images are there, `make dist` will include the images. You can either change the path to `pixmaps` in `Makefile.am` (the one in the project root), or move your images to `pixmaps`.